# jQuery function by window resize and function after window resize without click, only resizing

Tags: jquery, function, resize, hide

Hello i have a one problem with jQuery, i need function where by .resize function hide body content elements and after .resize function show body content elements, can you help me ?

Comment: please share what you have tried. your requirement is not at all clear

Comment: Are you trying to make the site responsive? where if the window size is to small certain elements are hidden?

Comment: page is responsive and i can use fade in/fade out preloader effect by resizing, if is page resizing i can fade out content and **after** resizing can i show content, solution on roasted work fine, i need only estetic effective solution, thats all, **thans for yours time peaple!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about window onresize event:

```
(function(){  // closure to avoid global variable
    var timeoutResize;
    $(window).on('resize',function(){
        $('body').hide();
        clearTimeout(timeoutResize);
        timeoutResize = setTimeout(function(){
             $('body').show();
        },100);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$("yourObjectToResize").resizable({
    start: function () {
        $('body').hide();
    },
    stop: function () {
        $('body').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: why use jquery ui when you can use jquery?

Comment: Maybe that is not better way but is one possible way. With jQuery UI is easier catch start and stop resize events.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    alert('You resized the window!');
    // do your hiding / showing here
});
```

The resize function is trigged while you drag the edges or corners of your window.
If you only want to trigger your actions when the resizing has ended, you can add a timeout.

If you want to show/hide stuff depending on the window size you could also consider using responsive design with CSS:

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/introduction-responsive-web-design/

(just a link, did not read it myself)